# Close reason for "cannot reproduce"

Tags: discussion, closing

<sup>(originally asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325529))</sup>

How should questions be closed where the problem described cannot be reproduced? One example is [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348013). The exact same thing that the asker describes as not working works perfectly fine for me. Of course the question can stay open for now, while waiting for the asker to respond with more details, but what if they don't answer?

Is it then "unclear", because it's unclear where the real problem is?

Or "too broad", because there could be many reasons that the asker didn't talk about, which could cause this problem (like not typing the commands right, not activating the system, not meeting the conditions they're trying to match, …)?

Comment: We should probably wait until every other user of the site has been unable to reproduce an issue before closing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd choose Unclear:

> #### Unclear what you're asking
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or **add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.** As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Emphasis mine. If you are unable to reproduce the issue using the exact steps provided, it is likely the question OP has witheld some other information, either because they forgot, or they deemed it 'non vital'.

For example, there's a few unknowns that I can see from that linked question:

- Fresh world or existing world?
  <sub>Some other command could be overriding the one they're looking at</sub>
- Is OP using mods?
  <sub>A mod could be modifying how commands are processed under the hood, either by-design or accidentally</sub>
- Single or multiplayer?
  <sub>Some servers may have certain restrictions enabled or be running mods themselves</sub>

Point is, if you're unable to reproduce the error, then the OP should *"add additional details to highlight exactly what [they] need"*, which befits the 'Unclear' close reason, in my opinion.

Comment: Agree 100%. Going even further, to address the "what if they don't answer" part, if they don't come back with an answer, then it's definitely not worth keeping a question open where the OP didn't even respond to a request for more details. If it's not important to them, why should it be important to anyone else, and that kind of unanswerable question has no value on the site.